# Gridview not rendering the same locally

Tags: vb.net, gridview

So I have a gridview that I am adding borders with the following on RowDataBound

```
       For Each tc As TableCell In e.Row.Cells
          tc.Attributes("style") = "border-width:1px;"
       Next
```

The odd thing is, if i run it locally, I won't see the borders, however, once moved to the server, they will render properly.  Has anyone else run into this issue?

edit: 
  I thought it might be helpful to state that this is an old 2.0 app that has been converted to 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
tc.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("border-width", "1px")
```

something to consider from your original code:

```
tc.Attributes("style") = "border-width:1px;"
```

this will replace any existing inline style that may exist for the table cell with ONLY the border width property that your setting, which is fine if that's what needs to be done.

Adding to the CssStyle collection will append a style to an existing set of inline styles.

Comment: gives the error: "Property access must assign to the property or use its value."

Comment: that is almost all of it.  I found that I need to also do a "tc.Attributes.Remove("border-width")" before adding it to get it to work.

Comment: no - do this: `tc.Attributes.CssStyle("border-width") = "1px"` this will add/replace as necessary